# Laravel. Query Builder groupBy

Tags: php, laravel, controller

So I have table named "**orders**" that has receipt_id to link it with the table named "**receipts**"

I want to group the orders that has the same receipt_id, so in my controller, I used this code;

```
        $orders = DB::table('orders')
        ->where('status', 0)
        ->groupBy('receipt_id')
        ->get();

    return $orders;
```

But unfortunately, it only returns the first one. I have a feeling that I shouldn't be using groupBy.

This is what it currently returns;

```
{
id: 1,
item: "12",
qty: 123,
price: "1823.00",
subtotal: "123.00",
receipt_id: 123,
status: 0,
created_at: null,
updated_at: null
}
```

EDIT:

I only want to query the **receipts** table, here's what my blade looks like right now and commented what I want to accomplish.

```
@forelse($orders as $order)
        <div class="col-md-4">
            <div class="panel panel-default">
                <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                    {{$order->receipt_id}}
                </div>

                <div class="panel-body text-center">
                    <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                        <thead>
                            <th>Order</th>
                            <th>Quantity</th>
                        </thead>

                        <tbody>

                            //all orders that has the same receipt_id will be showed here.
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{$order->item}}</td>
                                <td>{{$order->qty}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </tbody>
                    </table>
                </div>

                <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                        <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Served
                    </button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        @empty

        @endforelse
```

EDIT: Database structure for receipts and orders.

receipts;

```
Schema::create('receipts', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->decimal('total');
            $table->decimal('vatable');
            $table->decimal('vat');
            $table->decimal('vat_exempt');
            $table->decimal('vat_zero');
            $table->decimal('amount_due');
            $table->decimal('cash');
            $table->decimal('change_due');
            $table->integer('receipt_id');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

orders;

```
Schema::create('orders', function (Blueprint $table) {
            $table->increments('id');
            $table->string('item');
            $table->integer('qty');
            $table->decimal('price');
            $table->decimal('subtotal');
            $table->integer('receipt_id');
            $table->boolean('status');
            $table->timestamps();
        });
```

Comment: If you have defined relationship it's easy to get all `receipts` of an `order`. see docs here https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/eloquent-relationships

Comment: your query seems right may you have same `receipt_id` for all the `orders` with `status 1` 
if i am wrong post some of your sample data ill make you an query

Comment: @SagarGautam I only want to query the "orders" table. Maybe this is hard to imagine so I edited my original post showing what my blade looks like.

Comment: @ArunpandianM I edited the main post to show what the query's returning.

Comment: check this in your db : `select * from orders where status != 0;` and let us know

Comment: @JanArielSanJose can you add your database structure for orders and receipts ?

Comment: @ArunpandianM Currently, I have two rows of data in orders that has status set to 0. It's just a flag so when the transaction was successful, it will turn to 1. So it didn't return any data with that. :)

Comment: @SagarGautam Yes, of course. I edited the main post. Thanks for helping.

Comment: So, one receipt can have many orders in your case, you have to define one to many relationship in above tables

Comment: @SagarGautam Okay, I'll try to apply that. By any case, do you have any suggestions what my blade's structure should be? It's like a queue for restaurants. 1 receipt id = any no. of orders, shown in 1 panel.

Comment: You can use Expand Collapse for this with list of receipt id and on click receipt id you can show a list or table of all orders associated with this id. Hope you understand.

Answer (score 1):

Somehow I managed to solve my problem and I'll share my codes of course. :)

controller;

```
$receipt_ids = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('status', 0)
            ->orderBy('receipt_id', 'asc')
            ->groupBy('receipt_id')
            ->get();

        $orders = DB::table('orders')
            ->where('status', 0)
            ->orderBy('receipt_id', 'asc')
            ->get();

        return view('kitchens.index', compact('receipt_ids','orders'));
```

blade;

```
@extends('layouts.app')

<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-body" style="overflow: scroll; height:85vh;">
        <div class="row">
            @forelse($receipt_ids as $receipt_id)
                <div class="col-md-4">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <div class="panel-heading text-center">
                            {{$receipt_id->receipt_id}}
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-body">
                            <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive">
                                <thead>
                                    <th>Name</th>
                                    <th>Quantity</th>
                                </thead>

                                <tbody>
                                @foreach($orders as $order)
                                    @if($receipt_id->receipt_id == $order->receipt_id)
                                        <tr>
                                            <td>{{$order->item}}</td>
                                            <td>{{$order->qty}}</td>
                                        </tr>
                                    @endif
                                @endforeach
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </div>

                        <div class="panel-footer clearfix">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success pull-right" style="margin-right: 10px;">
                                <i class="fa fa-check-circle" aria-hidden="true"></i> Served
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            @empty

            @endforelse
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```